# replacing an NSDecimalNumbers with another in NSArray crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a NSMutabelArray and I want to do some additions inside of it. I do this by calling a functions with then create a subarray with the items where the calculations have to be done on.

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)calculate:(NSMutableArray *)arrayToCalculate {

  while ([arrayToCalculate containsObject:(@"+")]) {
    NSUInteger signeLocation = [arrayToCalculate indexOfObject:(@"+")];

    [arrayToCalculate replaceObjectAtIndex:(signeLocation-1)
                                withObject:([[arrayToCalculate objectAtIndex:(signeLocation-1)]
                                             decimalNumberByAdding:[arrayToCalculate objectAtIndex:(signeLocation+1)]])];

    [arrayToCalculate removeObjectsAtIndexes:
      [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange((signeLocation), 2)]];
    }

    return [arrayToCalculate lastObject];
}
```

I initialised the arrayToCalculate by:

```
NSMutableArray *subArray =
  [inputArray subarrayWithRange:(rangeOfCalculationItems)];
```

Every time I run this code it crashes. I am pretty sure it is bc I used subarray on an NSMutableArray and initialised it as NSMutableArray even when the message gives me back a NSArray, but I don't know how I could fix it or it is even the problem.

Comment: What is the crash?

Comment: If i just run the Program it says signal SIGABRT by return UIApplicationMain in the main.file, if I go Step-by-Step it just stops working at the [arrayToCalculate replaceObjectAtIndex:(...)] instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your method and tested it like this:

```
    NSArray *items = @[
                       [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"1"],
                       @"+",
                       [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"2"]
                       ];

    NSLog(@"%g", [self calculate: [items mutableCopy]].floatValue);
```

The code works and the printed result was `3`. Your issue must be somewhere else. Are you sure your array is in fact mutable? Note `[items mutableCopy]`.